# AspNetCore.SpaServices Angular2 Set the Base Url to Sub Directory for Prerendering

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I'm currently working on a project based on the SPA Angular application template included in Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices. Info on the templates can be found at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

Out of the box, the solution is plugs directly into the MVC pipeline and redirects any url that isn't mapped to an existing route or physical file to a controller that pre-renders and serves the Angular2 app.

What I'm trying to do is make all this work with a subdirectory within the application as the sole entry point and root directory of the Angular app.

What I've done so far: (this based on the SPA Angular template and the bare minimum to prove the issue!)

1. Created a new project from the Microsoft SPA Templates `dotnet new angular -n DashboardTest` (`dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*` to install the templates package)
2. Removed all routing from `Startup.cs` and replaced with `app.UseMvc();`. This means that only routes I've explicitly defined will be mapped.
3. Added `[Route("/dashboard/{*angularRoute}")]` attribute to the `Index()` action on the `HomeController` to catch all requests to my chosen subdirectory of `/dashboard` and pre-render the angular app (the `Home/Index` view already contains `<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>` for pre-rendering.)
4. Updated the base href tag in `_Layout.cshtml` to `<base href="/dashboard" />` to correctly configure the angular app to treat `/dashboard` as it's root.

At this point everything appears to work beautifully, however behind the scenes the pre-rendering has broken. To prove this, load `view-source:http://localhost:5000/dashboard/counter` (in Chrome) - you'll see the rendered output is actually the `/home` route, not the `/counter` route as expected.

So, how do you configure SpaServices, more specifically the `<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">` TagHelper to base the angular app in a different subdirectory than the root of the application?

I've started digging through the source code at https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/Prerendering to try and work out where the pre-renderer gets the base url from but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

For the record, I'm doing this to enable me to cleanly extend an existing MVC application to use Angular2 for a new feature without extensive refactoring. There's also the possibility of running multiple Angular2 apps within the same webapp too which might prove useful later down the line.

Comment: James, did you ever come to any conclusions with this?

Comment: @R.Richards sadly not, I just ended up disabling pre-rendering in the end.

Comment: Thanks for following up! I appreciate that.